# c++ store functor in class

Tags: c++, functor, template-classes

I´ve created the following Event class:

Event.h

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include<string>

template<typename T>
class Event
{
    public:
        T fnktptr; //Error: field ‘Event<int()>::fnktptr’ invalidly declared function type
        Event();
        virtual ~Event();
};

#endif // EVENT_H
```

Event.cpp

```
#include "Event.h"

template<typename T>
Event<T>::Event()
{
    //ctor
}
template<typename T>
Event<T>::~Event()
{
    //dtor
}
// No need to call this TemporaryFunction() function,
// it's just to avoid link error.
void TemporaryFunction ()
{
    Event<int> TempObj;
}
```

Now I tested it with the following code and it works:

```
Event<int> event;
int t = 5;
event.fnktptr = t;
```

But finally, I want to use it with a functor like this:

```
Event<decltype(consumeInt)> event;
event.fnktptr = consumeInt;
```

But now I get a Error in the Event.h file:

```
T fnktptr; //Error: field ‘Event<int()>::fnktptr’ invalidly declared function type
```

Comment: Shouldn't  `T fnktptr;` be  `T * fnktptr;`?

Comment: Yes, you can't have an object of a function type, it is not allowed.

Comment: I tried it now with `T* fnktptr` and now I get these error: `undefined reference to Event<int ()>::Event()`

Error occured at `Event<decltype(consumeInt)> event;`

This is my function consumeInt:
`Event<decltype(consumeInt)> event;`

Comment: @SergeyA: What would be a working alternative for my problem? (Store a functor in a class for further use.)

Comment: You could use `decltype(&consumeInt)` instead.

Comment: @AlexMallinger, you can store a pointer to function or an `std::function` object. The latter has benefits over function pointer.

Comment: @KurtStutsman, I tried your code with `T* fnktptr` and get these error: `cannot convert int() to int(**)() in assigment`.
If I try it with `T fnktptr` I get `undefined reference to Event<int (*)()>::Event()`

Comment: 1) You can't have a member of type function. 2) When you fixed that to a pointer, you have to define templates in the header file.

Comment: @Barry, how should I fix this to a pointer? Could you give me an example? 2) I use a workaround to split implementation and declaration with the `TemporaryFunction()`

Comment: @AlexMallinger Using `decltype(&consumeInt)` works when you leave it as `T fnktptr`. Since you were using it to store an `int` before you will have to leave it as your initial design.

Comment: @KurtStutsman: I don´t wanna store the int result. I wanna store a pointer to the function.

Comment: @KurtStutsman, But if I try it with my initial code  I get `undefined reference to Event<int (*)()>::Event()` with `decltype(&consumeInt)`.

Comment: I wanna store instances of the `Event` in a vector. In the next step, I would pass the vector of `Events` to a Function `run()` in that I will call `fnktptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your latest comments, I would say a `std::function<>` is the best way forward. The example code below assumes you just want to call `fnktptr` and don't care about the result.

```
#include <functional>

class Event
{
    public:
        std::function<void ()> fnktptr;
        Event();
        virtual ~Event();
};
```

If you need to capture the result, you will not be able to arbitrarily have different returns for each `Event` object. You either must pick one or use something like `boost::variant<>`.

```
template<class T>
class Event
{
    public:
        std::function<T ()> fnktptr;
        Event();
        virtual ~Event();
};
```

This would allow you to create `Event<int>` objects for instance to use with `consumeInt()`.

Example:

```
Event<int> event;
event.fnktptr = consumeInt;
```

Comment: Many thanks! Now It works for me with the `std::function<T ()> fnktptr;` solution.